# How to remove default "web server (HTTP)" outgoing port from Routing and remote access windows 2012 server

Tags: windows-server-2016

Added print screen where windows add default firewall port forwarding rules ant not allow to remove them. It is possible to remove or change outgoing port?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new 'Service' and call it whatever you like with whatever port you want. The services you're looking at are for standards and the HTTPS standard is TCP/443 and HTTP is 80/TCP. That's why you can't change it.

Comment: same port not allowed.